# How to check list in list with another list

Tags: python-3.x

I have list in list:

```
a = [
  [123123, 'juststring', '129.123.41.4'],
  [456456, 'usrnm', '129.123.41.4'],
  [78970, 'Something', '129.123.41.4']
]
```

I have another list:

```
b = [123123, 354634, 54234, 6734]
```

If `b` contains numbers in `a`, must put 'YES' or 'NO'

Output:

```
a = [[123123, 'juststring', '129.123.41.4', 'YES'], [456456, 'usrnm', '129.123.41.4', 'NO'], [78970, 'Something', '129.123.41.4', 'NO']]
```

This is my code:

```
for i in range(len(tbl_list)):
    for l in tbl_list:
        for p in pid:
            if int(l[0]) == int(p):
                tbl_list[i].append('YES')
                break
            else:
                tbl_list[i].append('NO')
                break
```

```
def draw_table():
    global tbl_list
    global pid
    for i in range(len(tbl_list)):
        for l in tbl_list:
            for p in pid:
                if int(l[0]) == int(p):
                    tbl_list[i].append('YES')
                    break
                else:
                    tbl_list[i].append('NO')
                    break
        tbl.add_row(l)
    print(tbl_list)
    print(tbl.draw())
    tbl.reset()
    tbl.header(Heading)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: what you want to ask here?

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
a = [[123123, 'juststring', '129.123.41.4'], [456456, 'usrnm', '129.123.41.4'], [78970, 'Something', '129.123.41.4']]

b = [123123, 354634, 54234, 6734]

for list_a in a:
    if any(pid == list_a[0] for pid in b):
        list_a.append('YES')
    else:
        list_a.append('NO')

print(a)
```

Comment: Thank you very much : )

Comment: Bro, thank you again after few years later, you just help me again.